# Reverse DNS record is not recognized

Tags: dns-zone, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I have a problem creating a reverse DNS record.

First of all, I have created a new zone. IP was aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd and Domain was ccc.bbb.aaa.in-addr.arpa.

Second, I have edited the just created zone and I added a PTR record:ddd IN PTR domain.com, TTL 14400

After I saved it and go again to edit the zone, I can see that system added .ccc.bbb.aaa.in-addr.arpa. to the record.

Anyway, after 24 hours, I connected to the console using SSH and run this command: `dig -x aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` I saw this output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-16.P2.el7_8.6 <<>> -x aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10280
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ddd.ccc.bbb.aaa.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ddd.ccc.bbb.aaa.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN    PTR     unknown.ord.scnet.net.

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 64.202.97.1#53(64.202.97.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 15 17:33:52 -04 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 91
```

As you see, this value is shown for the PTR record: `unknown.ord.scnet.net` and I cannot get rid of it.

What is wrong?

Comment: Try running `dig ccc.bbb.aaa.in-addr.arpa. ns`, and you'll see which servers are actually authoritative for that zone. They're not yours. Generally, they'll belong to your ISP.

Answer (score 4):

You don't own the IP address so you can't change the PTR record. Only the IP address owner -- your hosting provider -- can do that. You will need to contact them to find out how to change the record. Most providers have some sort of control panel that provides this functionality.